# java code, question mark and two dots

Tags: java

Hi I don't know what this line of code does

```
res = (actual.left != null) ? actual.left:actual.right;
```

what does the    ? do and the    : in     actual.left:actual.right

thanks

Comment: It's a [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), shorthand for it-then-else

Comment: It's  a  conditional expression. The expression before the ? is evaluated as a boolean expression. If true, do what immediately follows the ? otherwise do what follows the :